# Conv3D size doesn’t make sense with NIFTI data?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, medical, nifti, niftynet

So I am writing custom dataset for medical images, with .nii (NIFTI1 format), but there is a confusion.

My dataloader returns the shape `torch.Size (1,1,256,256,51)` . But NIFTI volumes use anatomical axes, different coordinate system, so it doesn’t make any sense to permute the axes, which I normally would with volume made of 2D images each  stored separately in local drive with 51 slice images (or depth), as Conv3D follows the convention `(N,C,D,H,W).`

so `torch.Size (1,1,256,256,51)` (ordinarily 51 would be the depth) doesn’t follow the convention `(N,C,D,H,W)` , but I should not permute the axes as the data uses entirely different coordinate system ?

Comment: It is not really clear what do you mean by "entirely different coordinate system". Could you please elaborate on what is the problem? Also unclear what is your intention: do you have a pre-trained model you want to apply to the new data which is different from what the model was trained on? Or do you want to train a new model from scratch?

Comment: I want to train new model from scratch.  Since my model uses convolutional layer, which follows the convention of (N,C,D,H,W) but the shape that is returned from the dataloader is different (N,C,W,H,D).... but since the data is NIFTI Volumes, I am thinking I should not change the axes since the data follows anatomical coordinate system.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with the existing data? It has 3 dimensions as you would want for the 3d convolution. What am I missing?

Comment: should I keep the keep the axes as it is ? or should I permute it to (N,C,D,H,W) from (N,C,W,H,D)  ?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer in addition to upvoting (press a checkmark to the left of the answer). If some aspect of your question is unanswered consider leaving a comment with details on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pytorch 3d convolution layer naming of the 3 dimensions you do convolution on is not really important (e.g. this layer doesn't really have a special treatment for depth compared to height). All difference is coming from kernel_size argument (and also padding if you use that). If you permute the dimensions and correspondingly permute the kernel_size parameters nothing will really change. So you can either permute your input's dimensions using e.g. `x.permute(0, 1, 4, 2, 3)` or continue using your initial tensor with depth as the last dimension.

Just to clarify - if you wanted to use `kernel_size=(2, 10, 10)` on your DxHxW image, now you can instead to use `kernel_size=(10, 10, 2)` on your HxWxD image. If you want all your code explicitly assume that dimension order is always D, H, W then you can create tensor with permuted dimensions using `x.permute(0, 1, 4, 2, 3)`.

Let me know if I somehow misunderstand the problem you have.